# Reliability of inotifywait loop

Tags: bash, inotify

I have of bash script with a loop watching a directory recursively:

```
while true
do
    if path=`inotifywait -q -r -e create --format %w%f $watchpath`; then
        #modify file
    fi
done
```

If I'm not mistaken this comes with this problem:

If many files are created in that directory or the machine is busy with other tasks, a file could be created before `inotifywait` is reached again - which would mean that it would be ignored.

Is there a way to mitigate that? Perhaps there is way to continuously "watch" and process a stream/feed of modfied files instead?

Comment: See also: [How do I wait for a file in the shell script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/407301)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to run `inotifywait` in monitor mode, e.g:

```
inotifywait -m -q -r -e create --format '%w%f' "$watchpath" |
    while read -r path; do
        : # do something with path
    done
```

There still will be a race between processes though, I'm not sure there is a way to avoid race conditions using shell utilities.

Even the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) lists this under caveats.

> The inotify API identifies affected files by filename.  However, by
>          the time an application processes an inotify event, the filename may
>          already have been deleted or renamed.

Comment: There are still a few problems with that code. What if someone creates a `$'wathcpath/file\n/etc/passwd'` file for instance. See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [How do I wait for a file in the shell script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/407301)

Comment: It works Thank you `inotifywait -me create "$PWD" | while read path; do notify-send "$path"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Use monitor mode `-m` so `inotifywait` does not exit after filesystem change, but outputs to stdout instead. the you can pipe this stream into a readerscript that reads lines from inotofywait and does your processing.